# Converting WSG84 to UTM, rgdal alternatives

Tags: r, r-sf, rgdal, terra

I have numerous existing scripts in which I used `project()` from the `rgdal` package to convert WSG84 Latitude/Longitude coordinates into UTM. `rgdal` has intermittently been giving me headaches by randomly stopping to work after updates, which I was always able to fix by copying an older version into my package folder instead of installing newer versions from CRAN. This also has stopped working, now, and since `rgdal` is going to be retired during 2023, I'm trying to convert my code using a different package for the projection. This is where I'm stuck as I don't quite understand how to adapt it for other packages like `terra` or `sf`.

```
somelocations<-data.frame(id=c('X', "Y", "Z"),
                   Long=c(-156.6274,-156.6457,-156.6676),
                   Lat=c(20.8081,20.8292,20.8512))

require(rgdal)

rgdal::project(as.matrix(somelocations[,c('Long', 'Lat')]), "+proj=utm +zone=4N ellps=WGS84 +units=m"))

Error in rgdal::project(as.matrix(DASARs[, c("Long", "Lat")]), "+proj=utm +zone=4N ellps=WGS84 +units=m") : 
  target crs creation failed: Invalid value for an argument
In addition: Warning message:
PROJ support is provided by the sf and terra packages among others
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do that with "terra".

Your example data

```
somelocations <- data.frame(id=c('X', "Y", "Z"),
                   Long=c(-156.6274,-156.6457,-156.6676),
                   Lat=c(20.8081,20.8292,20.8512))
```

The "raw" approach, which is most similar to the one with rgdal:

```
library(terra)
project(as.matrix(somelocations[,c('Long', 'Lat')]), 
        "+proj=longlat", "+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=m")
#         [,1]    [,2]
#[1,] 746948.4 2302727
#[2,] 745008.7 2305036
#[3,] 742693.4 2307439
```

Or via a SpatVector (which could be useful for other reasons such as data analysis and mapping).

```
v <- vect(somelocations, geom=c("Long", "Lat"), crs="+proj=longlat")
p <- project(v, "+proj=utm +zone=4 +units=m")
crds(p)
#         [,1]    [,2]
#[1,] 746948.4 2302727
#[2,] 745008.7 2305036
#[3,] 742693.4 2307439
```

The reason why you get an error is that your PROJ4 string `"+proj=utm +zone=4N")` is not valid. You could use `"+proj=utm +zone=4 +north")`, but adding "+north" is redundant, just like adding "unit=m" as these are the defaults. I would also leave out `+ellps=WGS84` or replace it with (the default) `+datum=WGS84`. (see the [documentation](https://proj.org/operations/projections/utm.html))

Answer (score 2):

The {rgdal} package is by now superseded, and the package maintainer (who has since retired) is actively pushing the package users to consider other alternatives. Hence the big fat warning & pointer to {sf} and {terra}.

For converting Long Lat data to UTM zone 4N coordinates I suggest the following code.

The key parts are:

- converting from a regular data frame to {sf} data frame; this will give you the baseline for projection (where are you projecting from? are your original coordinates in decimal degrees, or meters? survey feet even?)
- apply `sf::st_transform()` to your sf object, converting from a known start to desired format

I have found it the easiest to specify Coordinate Reference Systems using EPSG codes, such as 4326 and 32604, rather than proj4strings as used in your code.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

somelocations<-data.frame(id=c('X', "Y", "Z"),
                          Long=c(-156.6274,-156.6457,-156.6676),
                          Lat=c(20.8081,20.8292,20.8512))

# this is the baseline - locations in WGS84
locations_sf <- somelocations %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("Long", "Lat"), crs = 4326)

# a visual check - do the locations look correct?
mapview::mapview(locations_sf)
```

[image: 3 points off the coast of Hawaii]

```
# this is the action!
locations_projected <- locations_sf %>% 
  st_transform(crs = "EPSG:32604") # see https://epsg.io/32604 for more info...

# do the coordinates look as expected?
locations_projected
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 742693.4 ymin: 2302727 xmax: 746948.4 ymax: 2307439
# Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 4N
#   id                 geometry
# 1  X POINT (746948.4 2302727)
# 2  Y POINT (745008.7 2305036)
# 3  Z POINT (742693.4 2307439)
```